# Add words to a Hunspell SpellEngine

Tags: nhunspell

I am using the Hunspell SpellEngine class and want to add custom words to one of the underlying Hunspell languages but cannot seem to find a method or property that will return a Hunspell() instance. For example, I create a LanguageConfig for en-US, add it to the SpellEngine but then I have no way via

```
SpellEngine["en-US"].
```

To add words to it as I would via

```
Hunspell h = new Hunspell();
h.Add(word);
```

Comment: Instead of adding words to a dictionary, how about adding a new dictionary?  I ask this because I know hunspell happily accepts pre-fab and custom dictionaries when run standalone:  "hunspell -d en_US,/path/to/my/dict  file-to-check.txt" (and you must have ..my/dict.aff and ../my/dict.dic files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add this functionality and release a new package

Comment: Package Version 1.2.5538.16545 is uploaded and the SpellFactory has now three new methods Add(), AddWithAffix() and Remove(). Use them the same way as with a Hunspell object.